# How fill an array with this values (for loop or lapply function)?

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, lapply

I have this values (simplify example):

```
a  #class numeric
 [1] 1 5 7 6 9
```

and this array:

```
res.tot <- array(NA,dim=c(2,1,5))
```

I need to fill the array `res.tot` with `a` values, in this way:

```
[[1]]
     [1]
[1] 1
[2] 1

[[2]]
     [1]
[1] 5
[2] 5

...
[[5]]
     [1]
[1] 9
[2] 9
```

in the array `res.tot` each value of `a` is repeated 2 times, and each repeated `a` value occupay a different z dimension.
I tried with `for` loop in this way:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)){
  res.1 <- data.frame(rep(a[i],2))
  res.tot[,,i] <- res.1
  }
```

R tell me:

```
Error in res.tot.1[, , i] <- res.1 : incorrect number of subscripts
```

How can do it with `for loop` or `lapply` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brute force solution:

```
> a <- c(1,5,7,6,9)
> res.tot <- array(NA,dim=c(2,1,5))
> for (i in 1:(dim(res.tot)[1])) {
+   for (j in 1:(dim(res.tot)[2])) {
+     for (k in 1:(dim(res.tot)[3])) {
+       res.tot[i,j,k] <- a[k]
+     }
+   }
+ }
> res.tot
, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5

, , 3

     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    7

, , 4

     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    6

, , 5

     [,1]
[1,]    9
[2,]    9
```

and here is a one-liner solution:

```
> res.tot[] <- rep(a,each=2)
> res.tot
, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5

, , 3

     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    7

, , 4

     [,1]
[1,]    6
[2,]    6

, , 5

     [,1]
[1,]    9
[2,]    9
```